# What is the command for indenting code in vim with syntastic plugin?

Tags: help-system

I need to know how to reindent the code with syntastic.

I have tried using:

```
:call Retab()   ## it is showing it's invalid
:call GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
```

I need a plugin support.Plz don't provide code for .vimrc.

Comment: gg=G does not work?

Comment: Syntastic is a linting plugin. It doesn't have anything to do with indenting.

Comment: so how can i indent it with some other plugin.Plz help!!

Comment: What do you need a plugin for? Try using Vims native indenting feature first, before you go looking for a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use vims built in auto-indentation with the command (from normal mode type the following):

```
gg=G
```

You may also like to ensure you have set the necessary settings in your `.vimrc` so your indentation is how you want it (eg `shiftwidth` `tabstop` `expandtab` etc)